# Tag ID is not working after window.location in jQuery

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to redirect the browser and adding a hash on the end containing an element ID. Then, after it loads with the hash I want to process the page based on the ID that was passed in the hash. However, whenever I try to get the ID either as $('#' . newHash) or document.getElementById(newHash) it comes back as undefined.

Here is my code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  if(!document.location.hash && document.location.hash != "#") {
    jQuery.ajax({
      url: 'index.php',
      type: 'get',
      data: 'inMain=1',
      success: function(results){
        document.getElementById('mainBody').innerHTML = results;
        document.getElementById('mainHeader').innerHTML = 'Dashboard';
      }
    });
  }

  $(document).ready(function() {
    // check current window location
    var url = $(location).attr('href');
    // var hash_id = url.substring(url.indexOf('#') + 1);
    hash_id = document.location.hash;
    alert(document.location.hash.length);

    if (document.location.hash.length > 1) {
      activeHash = document.location.hash;
      test = document.getElementById(activeHash);
      alert("This: " + $('#' + activeHash.href) + " or This" + document.getElementById(activeHash).href);
    }

    $(function(){
      //Handle click events from your selector
      $(document.body).on("click", "[id^=navLink]", function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        newHash = "go" + this.id;
        window.location = "#" + newHash;
      });
    });
  });
</script>
```

The URL would be http://server.com/index.php#destinationId and the HTML would look something like this:

```
<a id="destinationId" href="/somepage.php">Some Page</a>
```

Thank you

Comment: Did you try to use `window.location.hash` instead of `document.location.hash`?

Answer (score 0):

Well, upon tweaking with it some more I've found that document.getElementById(activeHash) works, but $('#' + activeHash) does not.